# CSS in HTML colour

Tags: html, css

I want to make a heading in a certain colour but only that one heading and nothing else but it isn't working for me.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> website </title>
    <style type="text/css">
  body {
    color: #0066FF;
    background-color: #66FF33 }
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> heading </h1>
    <h3> sub heading </h3>
    <p> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

    </body>
</html>
```

I only want the heading to change colour. If you can also tell me how to individually change the text and sub heading colour it would be nice.

Comment: I dislike referring to this site, but it comes up first when you do a google search for "css", it does have decent tutorials even if they aren't always 100% accurate, and it does hold the answers you seek. On page 1.  http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    h1 {
        color: #0066FF;
        background-color: #66FF33 }  /* this will change all h1 tags (heading) */

    h3 {
        color:red; } /* this will change all h3 tags (sub-heading) */

    p { 
        color:blue; } /* this will change all paragragh (P) tags */

    /* And a few more examples: */

    .someClass { color:green; } /* this will change all elements with the attribute class="someClass" to green */

    #someID { color: purple; } /* this will change an element with the id of someID to purple (there should only be one) */
</style>
```

This will change the style of the `<h1>`, `<h3>`, and `<p>` tags.  Also you're missing a closing paragraph tag (`</p>`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> website </title>
    <style type="text/css">
  body {
    color: #0066FF;
    background-color: #66FF33 }
  #own_color {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id="own_color"> heading </h1>
    <h3> sub heading </h3>
    <p> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

    </body>
</html>
```

The code above is for just ONE header. If you want the same CSS-style for two or more headers you'll need to change the # to a dot(.) which representing a class. And type for example:  heading .

Comment: If he's changing it to a class, then he also needs to add a class attribute to the element (instead of using id)

Comment: I created a ID called #own_color. And it just says that the font color should be white. If you type .own_color (a class) and write <h1 class="own_color">Test</h1> it will we white. You can use this (or rename it) class on almost every tag in your HTML-file.

ID (#): Is used to specify a style for a single, unique element.
CLASS (.): The class selector is used to specify a style for a group of elements. Unlike the ID selector, the class selector is most often used on several elements.

Comment: Yes indeed Adam Plocher. Use a CLASS for several specified elements. And a ID for a unique element. You can also add CSS to every tag as Adam described before.

Comment: But since there should only ever be one h1 on a page it doesn't really need an id.

Comment: Yeah, if it's just one <h1> you can style the tag.